# Why does calculating 1/(n * log(n) - n) break the computer?

Tags: php, math, sum, inverse

Recently I stumbled on the problem [Wolfram says sum diverges, but Mathematica gives a numerical value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185209/wolfram-says-sum-diverges-but-mathematica-gives-a-numerical-value-for-infinite). It says that `1/(n * log(n) - n)` is not summable (or does not converge mathematically to be correct). The interesting point is that we can still try to calculate the sum numerically, despite the fact that it is 'not summable'. Mathematica gives ~ `6.1` as the numerical answer.

OK. I think, let's try to reproduce that number (or something similar) in a PHP script of that series summation. My code was:

```
$formula = function ($n) {return 1/($n * log($n) - $n);};
$n=2;
$sum=0;

while(true) {
    $term_n = $formula($n);
    $sum += $term_n;
    if ($n++ % 100000 == 0) {
        if ($sum > 5.8)
            usleep(1000);
        echo "n=".number_format($n-1)."; sum={$sum}; error={$term_n}\n";
    }
}
```

My algorithm computed the answer till `5.866` and then one of two things was happening:

1. either Ubuntu was crashing / freezing
2. Or Linux killed my computation script process

This happened after approximately 34 million iterations.

Later I inspected how the CPU load was changing in relation to calculating more series terms.

Now, the interesting part:
at approximately 22 million iterations the cores showed difficulty switching tasks between themselves:
[image]

Later on, at approximately 33 million iterations, the cores reached a point of no return - they refused to work at all:
[image]

The question is - **What's so special about sum `5.866` that it crashes a computer?** - given the fact that neither is the iteration number N very huge (just 34 million), nor the N-th term very small (just 1.7E-9) - so no reasons for a singularity.

Comment: so i probably should NOT be testing this code?

Comment: I would say in reverse - maybe by testing you'll find a bug in Intel CPU :-D

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: I expect the problem is caused by a memory leak in PHP. I reproduced your code in Python, and it ran without any difficulties.

Comment: I just ran it on PHP 7.1.10 (command line, not in Apache), I let it run up until `n=1,134,300,000; sum=6.0596079176871; error=4.4414755508302E-11`.  It did not crash, the system barely slowed down.  I have 4 CPU.  I run Mint 18.3 (4.15.0-38-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 20:16:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).  I can see a lot of switching between CPUs, but the total average did not go over ~60% total.  Now as to why it does that on your system, I cannot comment.

Comment: Judging from the source-code and your description of its behavior, perhaps you have stumbled upon a bug in your particular PHP version ...?  To begin with diagnosis, I would replace the `$formula($n)` bit with an in-line expression of the same thing, and see if your code continues to die.

Comment: i would avoid the while() loop, it often ends up in infinite loop

Comment: I just ran it till 6.065 (1,267,400,000 iterations) and the PHP process allocated 4.5MB of memory with one core up to 92.6% use. PHP 7.1.19 (cli). What version are you running this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but it sounds like the computer is running out of memory. Your script doesn't explicitly allocate any memory, but perhaps your version of PHP has a bug and is leaking memory somehow.

If free memory were exhausted, that could indeed cause the running OS to break down, or prompt it to kill your script to protect itself.

If the system started heavily using swap space to compensate, that would stall your script momentarily, causing the fluctuations in the CPU graphs that you observe.

Comment: Thanks, indeed a memory leak (script has eaten 100% RAM and later when swap usage has reached 100% - everything crashed). But seems that memleak is not in PHP core,- because same php version `PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli)` was executing my script in other machine without no problems of whatsoever. So as I understand there must be a memory leak in Ubuntu OS calls from PHP or something ...

Comment: Perhaps a loaded PHP extension is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed down problem to it's roots - the more function calls executed in the script - the more ram is leaked-out. And it does not matter which function(s) are called - user defined, sin(), log() or min(,) or whatever. So I suspect this is a bug in PHP core which happens at some specific conditions / OS Kernel.

Test code :

```
define('AMOUNT', 2000000);

if ($argc == 1)
    for ($i=AMOUNT; $i <= 3*AMOUNT; $i+=AMOUNT) 
        shell_exec('php ' . __FILE__ . " {$i}");
else 
    for ($i=0; $i < $argv[1]; $i++)
        sin(1);
    /*
    Change line above into something without a function call to stop memory leak :
    $x++; // for example
    */
```

produces such memory leak graph :

[image]